# why does my perl ftp script get timed out on upload of a small file?

Tags: perl

I do no understand why my script below hangs and is timed out on transfer of a very small file. If someone can assist whether it is a problem of configuration, or whatever.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
 use strict;
 use warnings;

use Net::FTP;

my $host    = "server";
my $user    = "username";
my $pass    = "password";
#!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!


 my $ftp = Net::FTP->new($host, passive => 1, time => 360, Debug => 1) or die "Error connecting to $host: $!\n";
 $ftp->login($user, $pass) or die "Cannot login to $user: $!\n";
 $ftp->ascii();
 #!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

opendir(my $DIR, "./") or die $!;
my @files=readdir($DIR);
foreach my $file (@files){
 next if -d $file;
 next unless $file =~/^OBS_ZB/;
 for my $file(glob 'OBS_ZB*'){
  eval{$ftp->put($file, $file) or print("Can't send file $file\n")};
  if($@ =~ /Timeout/){
   print "Got a timeout Issue: $@";
  }
 }
}
#!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
print "copying ends\n";
exit 0;
```

Comment: Does it works manually? Do you consider using `Net::SFTP::Foreign`.

Comment: @vkk05: Net::SFTP::Foreign is not about FTP but SFTP, which is a completely different protocol. You cannot access an FTP server with SFTP.

Comment: Since you explicitly have `Debug` added it would be useful to actually include the debug output. Apart from that I see no error in the client, i.e. likely it will fail with other clients too and the problem is on the server side or in between (i.e. firewall).

Comment: I have another version which works manually but has the same problem as this one when run through crontab. This version fails both manually and in crontab. The sftp module is not used though it is included. I tried an sftp version but that has a configuration error. I should have removed "use Net::sftp:: Foreign" but I thought it was harmless leaving it there.